# How to round the corners of an image inside a padded border, css

Tags: html, css, image, styling

I know you can round the corners of images in CSS using border-radius. But I have a border around some images with 5px of padding between the image and border. Using border-radius rounds the border, but not the image inside it. Is there a way to round the image itself?

```css
.image-link {
    border: #2EC4B6 solid 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-3 order-2 order-md-1 dish-image">
                <a class="outer-link" href="../maindishes/butternut-chili.html">
                    <img class="img-fluid image-link" src="../maindishes/images/butternut-chili.jpg"
                        alt="picture of dish">
                </a>
           </div>
```

[image]
<--This is what it looks like if I only wrap the anchor tag.

Comment: You could put the border on the `<a>` element instead.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but the border of the anchor tag doesn't match the image. I added a picture of what it looks like in my original post. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Just move border and padding to outer link. And round image itself only.

See example:

```css
.outer-link {
    display: inline-block;
    border: #2EC4B6 solid 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 8px;
    line-height: 0;
}

.image-link {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="outer-link" href="../maindishes/butternut-chili.html">
    <img class="img-fluid image-link"src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000ff/ffffff&text=-image-" alt="Dummy Image">
</a>
```

---

**Updated:** Example has been updated to suggestions in discussion.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I tried that, but the link isn't the same size as the image, so the border doesn't fit nicely around it. Is there a way I can fix that? 

For more context, I am using the bootstrap grid system.

Comment: I expanded the html in my original post for more context.

Comment: I am sorry. But I don't get what you changed and for this not the status off your problem/question. In your example code you updated class names and html structure(?) but not the css. And from the picture it is not to see what the code is you use on the page... Tipp: use for example an image provided by a dummy-image-service (like in my example) or call url off original image if reachable in web and show the code from webpage with same issue. From your EXAMPLE code update: I assume you did not set link and image to `display: inline-block`. Maybe you would like to try that first ...

Comment: Basically, the outer link should have a somewhat **larger** radius (about 3px) to match the image - something like this -    https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oNYOgEE

Comment: Great. From codpen: so it seems to me now it works? ... one more additional hint: the padding at bottom is a little bit larger then the others. If you add `line-height: 0` to `.outer-link` you will be perfect. (Has something to to with image used as inline-element ... there is an automatic spacing after the image when image is used like an 'text-element'.)

Comment: I updated the code of example based on suggestion in discussion.

Comment: Thanks! It does seem to work when it's just this small snippit of code. So I'm guessing I messed something up with the grid system. I guess I need to do some more studying so I can understand bootstrap better.

Answer (score -1):

Add border radius value to css like this.

```
border-radius: 20%;
```